# Big data analysis in web applications

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, bigdata, google-cloud-datastore, bigtable

Let's say I have very large time series data. I store that very big data for example in a storage like Google BigTable. I can query and get the data very fast out of the storage. So I can handle the storage problem. Up to here the process is very efficient.

Now I have a web application. I want to analyze a big time series stored in BigTable and visualize the result. I want to do a statistical evaluation of that time series with over a million points in there. So I have a solution to store the time series, I can get the right time series out of the storage, but I don't know how to handle the time series when I get them out oif the storage.

Which server side tools do I have to use to handle the big data? Which methods are there to do that? Parallelization in backend and an aggregated visualization at the web front end? It is useless to be efficient in storing the data, when I can't use the big data in a same effective way.

Answer (score 3):

unless you want to reinvent it, use google bigquery instead of bigtable.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/what-is-bigquery

Comment: Ok, I can also use bigquery instead. But I still have the problem, how should I handle the data after getting out of the storage?

Comment: you dont get it out of storage raw. its a database. see the docs.

Comment: Let's say I have one billion entries in storage. And I want to build a simple average calculation over one million entries. How can I do that? I thought I have to get out the million entries and do my statistical analysis?

Comment: Ok, I understand. So I can build a normal web application and I can store the data from the application to datastore. After this I can load the data from datastore to bigquery. Then I can run my analysis and visualize the results. If I have real time sensor values, should I stream the values directly to bigquery? Can bigquery used as main storage for the webapplication?

Comment: yes it can be the main storage. however i havent compared the SLAs or pricing for datastore vs bigquery.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to BigTable/BigQuery, you can try [ATSD](https://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/), it already does what you need. It is a time series database based on HBase. It comes with built-in visualization and you can aggregate any amount of data directly in the widgets or retrieve aggregated data using the API. If you are storing sensor data, here is a good example use case: https://axibase.com/environmental-monitoring-using-big-data/

Answer (score 0):

For analysis and visualization of time series data, there is a pretty good solution called 'Metatron Discovery'. It provides most of the answers to the problems you are having. Check it out!